# Bootstrap Form Wizard - Preventing Progress until Step is Validated

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, wizard

I am using http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/ and so far, so good.

Since I'm using Step Validation with this form, I would like to prevent the user from progressing through the steps without validating them. This is fine with the PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons at the bottom of the wizard, but not so much with the TABS at the top, that are constantly active.

I am aware of the onTabClick and onTabShow methods but I'm not clear on how to check for completed steps or incomplete steps.

Comment: Do you want to disable tab links on the top completely?

Comment: at first, probably, but once a step is completed, the user should have the option to return to any step that is completed. So say there are 5 steps, and the user is on step 4 - they should be able to return to steps 1,2 and 3 at any time - and enabling the tabs for those steps would be the quickest way for the user to travel back to those tab content pages.  So, the logic would most likely be: if valid, enable tab, go to next tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How it works

- Example is based on http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/validation.html
- `onTabClick` - basically it works the same as `onNext`. It validates form fields of the current tab, one difference is that I'm checking if clicked tab was previous or next (by comparing `currentIndex` and `nextIndex` parameters), if it is previous, it's not validating any form fields. It's also important not to allow jumping from for example 1 to 3 step, only from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc. (thanks @imjosh).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $validator = $("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
      emailfield: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      namefield: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      urlfield: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        url: true
      }
    }
  });

  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
    'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
      var $valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
    },
    'onTabClick': function(activeTab, navigation, currentIndex, nextIndex) {
      if (nextIndex <= currentIndex) {
        return;
      }
      var $valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
      if (!$valid) {
        $validator.focusInvalid();
        return false;
      }
      if (nextIndex > currentIndex+1){
       return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/dOQyqJ?editors=1010)

Comment: I don't think there's any need for the tabNumber variable.  

Also, I added one more check:  if (index > currentIndex+1) to prevent skipping over unvalidated tabs.

And I combined all the validation logic into one function which is called by both event handlers. https://jsfiddle.net/wr5tv8em/3/

Comment: You are right! I will change this, but do we need that your second check? If you have for example 5 steps and you are on the step 3 there is no possibility that 1 and 2 are invalid at the moment.

Comment: Ah, Ok, I understand now, when first tab is valid I can jump to step 3.

Comment: @imjosh do you have any idea how to make it possible to jump from step 1 to 3? (step 2 has to be checked on the way). I know that validate jQuery plugin provides `ignore` option and if you set it to `ignore: []` then all fields will be checked (even hidden ones). The problem is that it will prevent jumping from step 1 to 2 (because it will check for fields in step 2 and they are empty).

Comment: This is AWESOME.. Thank you!!! I wish the documentation was a bit more thorough, I didn't even know all the other things you could pass through these functions.  The Tab Click works perfectly now. I'm sure I should be able to get the tab Show to take care of incomplete and complete styling now.

Comment: Yeah, documentation is bad ;)

Comment: yeah, I just took a wild guess that there was a 4th parameter.

Comment: @makshh I don't quite understand what you are asking. Maybe, is it possible to allow the user to jump from step 1 to step 3 provided that step 2 is already valid?  either keep track of the valid state of each tab, or maybe trigger click events for each tab between the current tab and the clicked tab... ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. I like your second solution, thanks!

Comment: I just thought some more about the click event solution. I'm not sure if/how it would actually work.  It might not be feasible that way.

Comment: I know, but it's a good idea to test and check if that works, your first approach is probably safer ;)

Comment: @makshh solved it.  just added it as an answer since the system is complaining about too many comments

Comment: @max What about my question on [Using Step Wizard in Application Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753630/using-step-wizard-in-application-form)? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

This works, won't allow you to skip over tabs unless they are valid, and if you try to skip, you'll end up on the first invalid tab instead (e.g. if tab1 and tab2 are valid, tab3 is invalid, and you click on tab4, you end up on tab3 instead)

https://jsfiddle.net/wr5tv8em/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $validator = $("#commentForm").validate({
          rules: {
            emailfield: {
              required: true,
              email: true,
              minlength: 3
            },
            namefield: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3
            },
            urlfield: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3,
              url: true
            }
          }
        });

        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
            'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
            'onNext': validateTab,
                    'onTabClick': validateTab
        }); 

      function validateTab(tab, navigation, index, nextIndex){
        if (nextIndex <= index){
          return;
        }
        var commentForm = $("#commentForm")
        var $valid = commentForm.valid();
          if(!$valid) {
              $validator.focusInvalid();
                return false;
            }

        if (nextIndex > index+1){
         for (var i = index+1; i < nextIndex - index + 1; i++){
           $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('show', i);
           $valid = commentForm.valid();
             if(!$valid) {
                 $validator.focusInvalid();
                 return false;
               }
         }

         return false;
        }
      }
});
```